# Reusable workflows in Document Approval Processes

Tags: workflow, document-library

Currently I've been trying to build a solution wherein you would bind to a document library and a Task List by some means and conduct a workflow Document Approval Process using them; this could be a different document library and task list in different spots in the SharePoint environment running a common process.

SharePoint Designer reusable workflows only allow binding to one content type at a time, ergo giving me no way of reaching out and starting an approval task on the document (unless I'm missing something).  Is there any way around this?  This is for Office 365 so think within those constraints.

I'd prefer not to have to code any solution (as this would be running on Office 365, it would have to be sandboxed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, there were some technical issues within my particular SharePoint installation that led me to believe I couldn't use a reusable workflow with approval process.  But you can.